# I want to write Devanagari using english text all the possible letters of hindi should appear like mobile key board. Is all this possible letter there

Tags: unicode, languages, hindi

℅ sample all possible hindi letters

```
\usepackage{devanagari}

\begin{document}

{\dn a aA i e u U}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It would have been better to shorten your title, and move the text of your question into the body of the question.  As things are, your title is a bit too brief to understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile uses Unicode.

Here is a method using Unicode font and a transliteration scheme adapted (for `#` and `&`) and expanded from basic velthuis scheme to cover many more glyphs in Unicode.

[image: all letters]

The command is `\vh{}`: type `\vh{ka}` and get `क`.

The method is find-and-replace, using an expl3 function.

You will need a suitable font for the glyphs, and you will need to compile with lualatex.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} 
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\newfontfamily\fdeva[Colour=blue,
Script=Devanagari,
Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Noto Serif Devanagari}
%=====

%------------------------------- print and run #1
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\tl_new:N \l_myts_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\cdr}{ m }{%
    \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl { #1 }
    { \ttfamily\color{blue}
  \detokenize{#1}
  }
  
  \enspace $\mapsto$ \enspace
  
  \tl_use:N \l_my_tl
}%


%----- Typing shortcut
\newcommand\scdvts[2]{%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myts_tl   { #1 }   { #2} 
}
%===
\newcommand\dovelthuis{%
%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myts_tl { ;; } { ሴ}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myts_tl { ; } { }
%
\scdvts  { dcandrabvirama }   { ꣴ } 
\scdvts  { candrabvirama }   { ꣳ } 
\scdvts  { candabspace }   { ꣲ } 
\scdvts  { cbavagraha }   { ꣷ } 
\scdvts  { anudatta }   { ॒ } 
\scdvts  { pushpika }   { ꣸ } 
\scdvts  { yaheavy }   { ॺ } 
\scdvts  { siddham }   { ꣼ } 
\scdvts  { eprish }   { ॎ } 
\scdvts  { udatta }   { ॑ } 
\scdvts  { filler }   { ꣹ } 
\scdvts  { nukta }   { ़ } 
\scdvts  { grave }   { ॓ } 
\scdvts  { acute }   { ॔ } 
\scdvts  { caret }   { ꣺ } 
\scdvts  { ..a= }   { ऄ } 
\scdvts  { ..e- }   { ऎ } 
\scdvts  { ..o- }   { ऒ } 
\scdvts  { .kha }   { ख़ } 
\scdvts  { ooe- }   { ॴ } 
\scdvts  { uue- }   { ॷ } 
\scdvts  { ddda }   { ॾ } 
\scdvts  { cmka }   { ꣬ } 
\scdvts  { cmna }   { ꣭ } 
\scdvts  { cmpa }   { ꣮ } 
\scdvts  { cmra }   { ꣯ } 
\scdvts  { cmvi }   { ꣰ } 
\scdvts  { cm.a }   { ꣱ } 
\scdvts  { head }   { ꣻ } 
\scdvts  { aa- }   { आ } 
\scdvts  { ii- }   { ई } 
\scdvts  { uu- }   { ऊ } 
\scdvts  { .r- }   { ऋ } 
\scdvts  { .l- }   { ऌ } 
\scdvts  { ai- }   { ऐ } 
\scdvts  { ~o- }   { ऑ } 
\scdvts  { au- }   { औ } 
\scdvts  { .th }   { ठ } 
\scdvts  { .dh }   { ढ } 
\scdvts  { nnn }   { ऩ } 
\scdvts  { lll }   { ऴ } 
\scdvts  { ooe }   { ऻ } 
\scdvts  { ..e }   { ॆ } 
\scdvts  { ..o }   { ॊ } 
\scdvts  { ~ee }   { ॕ } 
\scdvts  { uue }   { ॗ } 
\scdvts  { .ga }   { ग़ } 
\scdvts  { .Ra }   { ड़ } 
\scdvts  { Rha }   { ढ़ } 
\scdvts  { yya }   { य़ } 
\scdvts  { .R- }   { ॠ } 
\scdvts  { .L- }   { ॡ } 
\scdvts  { ~a- }   { ॲ } 
\scdvts  { oe- }   { ॳ } 
\scdvts  { aw- }   { ॵ } 
\scdvts  { ue- }   { ॶ } 
\scdvts  { dda }   { ॸ } 
\scdvts  { zha }   { ॹ } 
\scdvts  { gga }   { ॻ } 
\scdvts  { jja }   { ॼ } 
\scdvts  { bba }   { ॿ } 
\scdvts  { cma }   { ꣪ } 
\scdvts  { cmu }   { ꣫ } 
\scdvts  { cb2 }   { ꣵ } 
\scdvts  { cb3 }   { ꣶ } 
\scdvts  { .jo }   { ꣽ } 
\scdvts  { ay- }   { ꣾ } 
\scdvts  { /i }   { ऀ } 
\scdvts  { .m }   { ं } 
\scdvts  { .h }   { ः } 
\scdvts  { a- }   { अ } 
\scdvts  { i- }   { इ } 
\scdvts  { u- }   { उ } 
\scdvts  { ~e }   { ऍ } 
\scdvts  { e- }   { ए } 
\scdvts  { o- }   { ओ } 
\scdvts  { kh }   { ख } 
\scdvts  { gh }   { घ } 
\scdvts  { "n }   { ङ } 
\scdvts  { ch }   { छ } 
\scdvts  { jh }   { झ } 
\scdvts  { ~n }   { ञ } 
\scdvts  { .t }   { ट } 
\scdvts  { .d }   { ड } 
\scdvts  { .n }   { ण } 
\scdvts  { th }   { थ } 
\scdvts  { dh }   { ध } 
\scdvts  { ph }   { फ } 
\scdvts  { bh }   { भ } 
\scdvts  { rr }   { ऱ } 
\scdvts  { "s }   { श } 
\scdvts  { .s }   { ष } 
\scdvts  { oe }   { ऺ } 
\scdvts  { .a }   { ऽ } 
\scdvts  { aa }   { ा } 
\scdvts  { ii }   { ी } 
\scdvts  { uu }   { ू } 
\scdvts  { .r }   { ृ } 
\scdvts  { .R }   { ॄ } 
\scdvts  { ~a }   { ॅ } 
\scdvts  { ai }   { ै } 
\scdvts  { ~o }   { ॉ } 
\scdvts  { au }   { ौ } 
\scdvts  { \& }   { ् } 
\scdvts  { aw }   { ॏ } 
\scdvts  { .o }   { ॐ } 
\scdvts  { ue }   { ॖ } 
\scdvts  { qa }   { क़ } 
\scdvts  { za }   { ज़ } 
\scdvts  { fa }   { फ़ } 
\scdvts  { .l }   { ॢ } 
\scdvts  { .L }   { ॣ } 
\scdvts  { || }   { ॥ } 
\scdvts  { \# }   { ॱ } 
\scdvts  { gs }   { ॽ } 
\scdvts  { c0 }   { ꣠ } 
\scdvts  { c1 }   { ꣡ } 
\scdvts  { c2 }   { ꣢ } 
\scdvts  { c3 }   { ꣣ } 
\scdvts  { c4 }   { ꣤ } 
\scdvts  { c5 }   { ꣥ } 
\scdvts  { c6 }   { ꣦ } 
\scdvts  { c7 }   { ꣧ } 
\scdvts  { c8 }   { ꣨ } 
\scdvts  { c9 }   { ꣩ } 
\scdvts  { ay }   { ꣿ } 
\scdvts  { / }   { ँ } 
\scdvts  { k }   { क } 
\scdvts  { g }   { ग } 
\scdvts  { c }   { च } 
\scdvts  { j }   { ज } 
\scdvts  { t }   { त } 
\scdvts  { d }   { द } 
\scdvts  { n }   { न } 
\scdvts  { p }   { प } 
\scdvts  { b }   { ब } 
\scdvts  { m }   { म } 
\scdvts  { y }   { य } 
\scdvts  { r }   { र } 
\scdvts  { l }   { ल } 
\scdvts  { L }   { ळ } 
\scdvts  { v }   { व } 
\scdvts  { s }   { स } 
\scdvts  { h }   { ह } 
\scdvts  { i }   { ि } 
\scdvts  { u }   { ु } 
\scdvts  { e }   { े } 
\scdvts  { o }   { ो } 
\scdvts  { | }   { । } 
\scdvts  { || }   { ॥ } 
\scdvts  { 0 }   { \symbol{2406} } 
\scdvts  { 1 }   { \symbol{2407} } 
\scdvts  { 2 }   { \symbol{2408} } 
\scdvts  { 3 }   { \symbol{2409} } 
\scdvts  { 4 }   { \symbol{2410} } 
\scdvts  { 5 }   { \symbol{2411} } 
\scdvts  { 6 }   { \symbol{2412} } 
\scdvts  { 7 }   { \symbol{2413} } 
\scdvts  { 8 }   { \symbol{2414} } 
\scdvts  { 9 }   { \symbol{2415} } 
\scdvts  { @ }   { ॰ } 
%
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myts_tl { ሴ} { ; }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_myts_tl   { a }   {  } 
}

%=====
\NewDocumentCommand { \vh } { m } { \trvelthuis {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \trvelthuis } { m } {%
\tl_set:Nn \l_myts_tl { #1 }
\dovelthuis
\tl_use:N \l_myts_tl
}

%---- Environments

\NewDocumentEnvironment{velthuis}{ O{\fdeva} +b }
{
#1
\tl_set:Nn \l_myts_tl { #2 }
\dovelthuis
\tl_use:N \l_myts_tl
}
{ }

\ExplSyntaxOff





\begin{document}

\section{Sample}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\rowcolor{blue!7}
Input type & Example & Result \\
\hline
Direct input & \fdeva देवनागरी & \fdeva देवनागरी \\
Velthuis $l$3 & devanaagarii & \fdeva \vh{devanaagarii} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
Use \textbackslash \& for conjuncts: 
la + ba = {\fdeva \vh{laba}}; 
la + \textbackslash \& + ba = {\fdeva \vh{la\&ba}}

\bigskip
\small
\begin{multicols}{6}
\noindent /i = {\fdeva \vh{/i}}\par
\noindent / = {\fdeva \vh{/}}\par
\noindent .m = {\fdeva \vh{.m}}\par
\noindent .h = {\fdeva \vh{.h}}\par
\noindent ..a= = {\fdeva \vh{..a=}}\par
\noindent a- = {\fdeva \vh{a-}}\par
\noindent aa- = {\fdeva \vh{aa-}}\par
\noindent i- = {\fdeva \vh{i-}}\par
\noindent ii- = {\fdeva \vh{ii-}}\par
\noindent u- = {\fdeva \vh{u-}}\par
\noindent uu- = {\fdeva \vh{uu-}}\par
\noindent .r- = {\fdeva \vh{.r-}}\par
\noindent .l- = {\fdeva \vh{.l-}}\par
\noindent ~e = {\fdeva \vh{~e}}\par
\noindent ..e- = {\fdeva \vh{..e-}}\par
\noindent e- = {\fdeva \vh{e-}}\par
\noindent ai- = {\fdeva \vh{ai-}}\par
\noindent ~o- = {\fdeva \vh{~o-}}\par
\noindent ..o- = {\fdeva \vh{..o-}}\par
\noindent o- = {\fdeva \vh{o-}}\par
\noindent au- = {\fdeva \vh{au-}}\par
\noindent k = {\fdeva \vh{k}}\par
\noindent kh = {\fdeva \vh{kh}}\par
\noindent g = {\fdeva \vh{g}}\par
\noindent gh = {\fdeva \vh{gh}}\par
\noindent "n = {\fdeva \vh{"n}}\par
\noindent c = {\fdeva \vh{c}}\par
\noindent ch = {\fdeva \vh{ch}}\par
\noindent j = {\fdeva \vh{j}}\par
\noindent jh = {\fdeva \vh{jh}}\par
\noindent ~n = {\fdeva \vh{~n}}\par
\noindent .t = {\fdeva \vh{.t}}\par
\noindent .th = {\fdeva \vh{.th}}\par
\noindent .d = {\fdeva \vh{.d}}\par
\noindent .dh = {\fdeva \vh{.dh}}\par
\noindent .n = {\fdeva \vh{.n}}\par
\noindent t = {\fdeva \vh{t}}\par
\noindent th = {\fdeva \vh{th}}\par
\noindent d = {\fdeva \vh{d}}\par
\noindent dh = {\fdeva \vh{dh}}\par
\noindent n = {\fdeva \vh{n}}\par
\noindent nnn = {\fdeva \vh{nnn}}\par
\noindent p = {\fdeva \vh{p}}\par
\noindent ph = {\fdeva \vh{ph}}\par
\noindent b = {\fdeva \vh{b}}\par
\noindent bh = {\fdeva \vh{bh}}\par
\noindent m = {\fdeva \vh{m}}\par
\noindent y = {\fdeva \vh{y}}\par
\noindent r = {\fdeva \vh{r}}\par
\noindent rr = {\fdeva \vh{rr}}\par
\noindent l = {\fdeva \vh{l}}\par
\noindent L = {\fdeva \vh{L}}\par
\noindent lll = {\fdeva \vh{lll}}\par
\noindent v = {\fdeva \vh{v}}\par
\noindent "s = {\fdeva \vh{"s}}\par
\noindent .s = {\fdeva \vh{.s}}\par
\noindent s = {\fdeva \vh{s}}\par
\noindent h = {\fdeva \vh{h}}\par
\noindent oe = {\fdeva \vh{oe}}\par
\noindent ooe = {\fdeva \vh{ooe}}\par
\noindent nukta = {\fdeva \vh{nukta}}\par
\noindent .a = {\fdeva \vh{.a}}\par
\noindent aa = {\fdeva \vh{aa}}\par
\noindent i = {\fdeva \vh{i}}\par
\noindent ii = {\fdeva \vh{ii}}\par
\noindent u = {\fdeva \vh{u}}\par
\noindent uu = {\fdeva \vh{uu}}\par
\noindent .r = {\fdeva \vh{.r}}\par
\noindent .R = {\fdeva \vh{.R}}\par
\noindent ~a = {\fdeva \vh{~a}}\par
\noindent ..e = {\fdeva \vh{..e}}\par
\noindent e = {\fdeva \vh{e}}\par
\noindent ai = {\fdeva \vh{ai}}\par
\noindent ~o = {\fdeva \vh{~o}}\par
\noindent ..o = {\fdeva \vh{..o}}\par
\noindent o = {\fdeva \vh{o}}\par
\noindent au = {\fdeva \vh{au}}\par
\noindent \textbackslash\& = {\fdeva \vh{\&}}\par
\noindent eprish = {\fdeva \vh{eprish}}\par
\noindent aw = {\fdeva \vh{aw}}\par
\noindent .o = {\fdeva \vh{.o}}\par
\noindent udatta = {\fdeva \vh{udatta}}\par
\noindent anudatta = {\fdeva \vh{anudatta}}\par
\noindent grave = {\fdeva \vh{grave}}\par
\noindent acute = {\fdeva \vh{acute}}\par
\noindent ~ee = {\fdeva \vh{~ee}}\par
\noindent ue = {\fdeva \vh{ue}}\par
\noindent uue = {\fdeva \vh{uue}}\par
\noindent qa = {\fdeva \vh{qa}}\par
\noindent .kha = {\fdeva \vh{.kha}}\par
\noindent .ga = {\fdeva \vh{.ga}}\par
\noindent za = {\fdeva \vh{za}}\par
\noindent .Ra = {\fdeva \vh{.Ra}}\par
\noindent Rha = {\fdeva \vh{Rha}}\par
\noindent fa = {\fdeva \vh{fa}}\par
\noindent yya = {\fdeva \vh{yya}}\par
\noindent .R- = {\fdeva \vh{.R-}}\par
\noindent .L- = {\fdeva \vh{.L-}}\par
\noindent .l = {\fdeva \vh{.l}}\par
\noindent .L = {\fdeva \vh{.L}}\par
\noindent | = {\fdeva \vh{|}}\par
\noindent || = {\fdeva \vh{||}}\par
\noindent 0 = {\fdeva \vh{0}}\par
\noindent 1 = {\fdeva \vh{1}}\par
\noindent 2 = {\fdeva \vh{2}}\par
\noindent 3 = {\fdeva \vh{3}}\par
\noindent 4 = {\fdeva \vh{4}}\par
\noindent 5 = {\fdeva \vh{5}}\par
\noindent 6 = {\fdeva \vh{6}}\par
\noindent 7 = {\fdeva \vh{7}}\par
\noindent 8 = {\fdeva \vh{8}}\par
\noindent 9 = {\fdeva \vh{9}}\par
\noindent @ = {\fdeva \vh{@}}\par
\noindent \textbackslash\# = {\fdeva \vh{\#}}\par
\noindent ~a- = {\fdeva \vh{~a-}}\par
\noindent oe- = {\fdeva \vh{oe-}}\par
\noindent ooe- = {\fdeva \vh{ooe-}}\par
\noindent aw- = {\fdeva \vh{aw-}}\par
\noindent ue- = {\fdeva \vh{ue-}}\par
\noindent uue- = {\fdeva \vh{uue-}}\par
\noindent dda = {\fdeva \vh{dda}}\par
\noindent zha = {\fdeva \vh{zha}}\par
\noindent yaheavy = {\fdeva \vh{yaheavy}}\par
\noindent gga = {\fdeva \vh{gga}}\par
\noindent jja = {\fdeva \vh{jja}}\par
\noindent gs = {\fdeva \vh{gs}}\par
\noindent ddda = {\fdeva \vh{ddda}}\par
\noindent bba = {\fdeva \vh{bba}}\par
\noindent c0 = {\fdeva \vh{c0}}\par
\noindent c1 = {\fdeva \vh{c1}}\par
\noindent c2 = {\fdeva \vh{c2}}\par
\noindent c3 = {\fdeva \vh{c3}}\par
\noindent c4 = {\fdeva \vh{c4}}\par
\noindent c5 = {\fdeva \vh{c5}}\par
\noindent c6 = {\fdeva \vh{c6}}\par
\noindent c7 = {\fdeva \vh{c7}}\par
\noindent c8 = {\fdeva \vh{c8}}\par
\noindent c9 = {\fdeva \vh{c9}}\par
\noindent cma = {\fdeva \vh{cma}}\par
\noindent cmu = {\fdeva \vh{cmu}}\par
\noindent cmka = {\fdeva \vh{cmka}}\par
\noindent cmna = {\fdeva \vh{cmna}}\par
\noindent cmpa = {\fdeva \vh{cmpa}}\par
\noindent cmra = {\fdeva \vh{cmra}}\par
\noindent cmvi = {\fdeva \vh{cmvi}}\par
\noindent cm.a = {\fdeva \vh{cm.a}}\par
\noindent candabspace = {\fdeva \vh{candabspace}}\par
\noindent candrabvirama = {\fdeva \vh{candrabvirama}}\par
\noindent dcandrabvirama = {\fdeva \vh{dcandrabvirama}}\par
\noindent cb2 = {\fdeva \vh{cb2}}\par
\noindent cb3 = {\fdeva \vh{cb3}}\par
\noindent cbavagraha = {\fdeva \vh{cbavagraha}}\par
\noindent pushpika = {\fdeva \vh{pushpika}}\par
\noindent filler = {\fdeva \vh{filler}}\par
\noindent caret = {\fdeva \vh{caret}}\par
\noindent head = {\fdeva \vh{head}}\par
\noindent siddham = {\fdeva \vh{siddham}}\par
\noindent .jo = {\fdeva \vh{.jo}}\par
\noindent ay- = {\fdeva \vh{ay-}}\par
\noindent ay = {\fdeva \vh{ay}}\par
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```